# Boost/CentOS linking issue

Tags: boost, linker, centos

I'm trying to learn Boost threading.
I'm using code from a tutorial online, after some errors I realised that I needed a newer version of Boost so I downloaded the latest version of it into a directory, unzipped it and installed it with the commands:

```
./bootstrap.sh
./bjam install
```

The sample code I'm trying to run is this:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp> 
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

void threader()
{ 
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
  { 
    sleep(1); 
    cout << boost::this_thread::get_id() << "-" << i << endl;
    //cout << "-" << i << endl;
  } 
} 
int main() 
{ 
  thread t(threader);
  sleep(1);
  thread u(threader);
  t.join(); 
  u.join(); 
}
```

I compiled with the same line I used with the old version of Boost(1.33 as comes with Centos as standard):

```
g++ -Wall -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_thread threadtest.cpp -o threadtest
```

It compiled without error (unlike with the old version of Boost) but when I run threadtest I get:

```
./threadtest: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_thread.so.1.47.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Looking into the /usr/local/lib dircetory I can see the following:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   217270 Nov 10 12:50 libboost_thread.a
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       25 Nov 10 12:43 libboost_thread.so -> libboost_thread.so.1.47.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   138719 Nov 10 12:43 libboost_thread.so.1.47.0
```

So I cannot see why it's not working.
I think it's to do with the -lboost_thread part of the compilation line.
I tried linking to the library directly with:

```
g++ -Wall -L/usr/local/lib libboost_thread.a threadtest.cpp -o threadtest
```

But it again can't find the file.
Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to re-add the path of my lib directory to my LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the following:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/lib/"
```

That did the trick.